# Error waiting for EKS Node Group creation: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create an EKS cluster and a node group on AWS using Terraform. While doing so, an error is thrown in the apply phase:

```
Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (prod-gitlab-runner:core_node_group) creation: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the Kubernetes cluster.
```

The EKS cluster retrieves and uses public and private subnets from an existing VPC. The public subnet:

1. Has "Auto-assign public IPv4 address" enabled
2. Is associated with an ACL
3. Is associated with NAT gateway (same result on associating it with Internet Gateway)
4. Is associated with a route table (which has entry `0.0.0.0` corresponding to the NAT gateway)

The EKS cluster is created but the node group is not.

How do I ensure that the `terraform apply` phase completes execution with the node group being a part of the EKS cluster ?

Comment: Have you assigned your roles with the predefined policies shown in the terraform docs? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group

Comment: Yes I have as per the "Example usage"